# Namespace 'Windows' not found in Unity UWP app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, namespaces, assembly-references

I'm trying to set up a basic UWP project in Unity and use parts of the Windows namespace.*
However, no matter which part of the Windows namespace I try to import in my script, I always get

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Build support both for Windows and UWP is set up in Visual Studio and Unity and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0) is installed. Any other ideas how to fix this?

Based on https://forum.unity.com/threads/windows-storage-is-missing-when-building-for-uwp-hololens.541415/ I would have assumed that Windows is available in Unity for UWP as they were able to fix it there?

Thanks

---

*In the long run, I am trying to use 'Windows.Devices.Input.Preview' to access Gaze Input in a project that also uses Vuforia and thus needs to be UWP. Other tips on how to combine Gaze Tracking and Marker recognition in Unity are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows namespace in Unity is made for Windows PC build only. It won't work for other systems. On the top of the script try to add a

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
```

You should add the whole declaration like

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
Use SpeechRecognitionEngine class
```

#endif

If you are building for android or ios you will need also to add:

```
 #if UNITY_ANDROID  
Use SpeechRecognizer class
```

#endif

#if UNITY_IOS
Use SFSpeechRecognizer class
#endif

Comment: It's for a UWP build, so no iOS/Android, but it needs to be run on UWP. Fixing the error message by ignoring the code outside standalone won't help unfortunately.